# xticks and yticks issues while using imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, scikit-image, xticks

I've a problem with fixing the `xticks` and `yticks` for the `imshow` plot. When I use the single plot for `imshow` then the extent works better (see first figure below). However, when I use to insert the coordinates of the local maxima on the `imshow` plot then the ticks have changed (second figure). Can anybody help me to fix the `xticks` and `yticks` after plotting the local maxima.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max

# Input of a 2D array/ 
data = np.real(data) # data link : https://www.file.io/LvDn/download/WqdRCoW2dUPV

# Find the coordinates of local maxima in the data
coordinates = peak_local_max(data, min_distance=8,  num_peaks=2) #, threshold_abs = 0.0004) #
# Display results

kf=2*2*np.pi/10
resolution = 40
N=9
kx = np.linspace(-kf, kf, N * resolution)  # space vector
ky = np.linspace(-kf, kf, N * resolution)  # space vector


fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(13, 8), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax = axes.ravel()
ax[0].imshow(data, cmap='seismic', vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max(),
                       extent=[kx.min(), kx.max(), ky.min(), ky.max()],
                       interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')
ax[0].axis('on')
ax[0].set_title('Original')
```

The above code snippet generates this plot:

[image: Fig. 01]

Here, the imshow extent works fine and that is desired for me. When I use the script to plot the local maxima, then the ticks are changed as shown below.

```
ax[1].imshow(data, cmap='seismic')
ax[1].autoscale(False)
ax[1].plot( coordinates[:, 1], coordinates[:, 0], 'k.', marker='o', markersize=12)
ax[1].axis('on')
ax[1].set_title('Peak_local_max')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[[image: Fig. 02]

How do I fix the `xticks` and `yticks` in the plot for "Peak Local Maxima"?

If I use the extent for the script of 2nd plot then the figure looks like this:

[image: Fig. 03]

Comment: You are sharing the axes, and in the second plot you change the axes to 0-352 (or whatever) so the "Original" changes its limits as well.  Either don't share, or set the extent in the second imshow.

Comment: @JodyKlymak, thanks for the response. When I use the extent for the 2nd plot then the figure looks as in Fig. 03. The problem for me is  how to impose the coordinates of local maxima on the imshow plot? The ticks in Fig. 03 are OK, but missing the local maxima [dark spots]. Do you have a solution?

Comment: presumably you need to do a bit of math and translate pixels to whatever you are setting the extent in....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure what you're asking for, and the example code you provide doesn't work. Variables like `spec` are undefined for example.

But I'm guessing the main issue is that you're mixing pixel (from `peak_local_max`) and data coordinates. Which you can fix with:

```py
extent = [kx.min(), kx.max(), ky.min(), ky.max()]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(13, 8), sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax[0].set_title('Original')
ax[0].imshow(data, cmap='seismic', extent=extent)

ax[1].set_title('Peak_local_max')
ax[1].imshow(data, cmap='seismic', extent=extent)
ax[1].plot(kx[coordinates[:, 1]], ky[coordinates[:, 0]], 'go', markersize=12)
```

The extent that Matplotlib uses also should be the outer extent, I'm not sure of your coordinate arrays `kx` and `ky` actually are that. That can cause a mismatch/shift in the order of half the resolution.

[image]